# Use and monitor a LiFePO4 battery with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, bms, lifepo4, battery-monitor

I am planning to build a small robot using a Raspberry Pi Pico microcontroller and DC motors. I am considering to use a single cell LiFePO4 battery.

After some research, it looks like many use a *Battery Management System* for such batteries. On the other hand, most such systems use multiple battery cells and has many features e.g. charging.

I would like to keep my project simple, but I also want to do most of it myself, for learning. I am planning to charge my battery in an external charger, so my project does not need to support battery charging and overcharge protection.

Since my project is quite simple, I am considering to add only basic necessary monitoring of the battery.

**What are the necessary battery monitoring that I need?**

- I have understood, that I at least should add a voltage divider to monitor so that the battery voltage does not go under ~2.9-3.0V, via ADC on the microcontroller.

I see that some BMS has features related to cell-balancing, but I am planning to use a single cell and no support for charging.

**Are there more properties that is necessary to monitor?**

Comment: Use a thermistor to monitor the cell temperature, and a good voltage reference to monitor the cell voltage. The cut-off voltage has to not just have precision, but must also be accurate (and you need to know the difference).  Do LiFePO4 cells catch fire?  Do your own research. But if the answer is yes, you may want to learn with something that doesn't catch fire if you make a mistake. Also, unless your single cell is powerful, or your motors are small, you may be underpowered. Measure the motor to see how much power it needs for the torque +  speed you need.

Comment: The last section of your question causes your question to lack focus (you're asking too many questions). My suggestion -- delete the last section, get an answer with this question, then ask another question that covers the deleted section.